# mapping components in a row

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how can I map components in a row and not in column as the default way? I tried using `flexDirection: 'row'` on the mapped component but without much luck. I also tried to set the `ScrollView` with `flexDirection: 'row'` but it wont help.

the desirable result is

```
...
@@@@@@@@@@@@@

@@@@@@@@@@@@@

@@@@@@@@@@@@@

@@@@@@@@@@@@@
...
```

what I get is:

```
...

@

@

@

@

@

...
```

CODE:

```
  <ScrollView style={{width:'80%'}}>
  {
    this.budgetHolder.map((budge) => {
      return (
        <Text style={{color:this.colorHolder, flexDirection: 'row'}}>@</Text>
      )
    })

  }
  </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have a View with the style flex: 1 around it and then you can use the direction row and from there can list whatever you need side by side.

If you notice to get it to use 80% of the screen I break it down so 80% = 1/percent I want so .8. This pattern makes it very easy to build scaleable screens

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.row}>
    {
      this.budgetHolder.map((budge) => {
       return (
         <Text style={{color:this.colorHolder, flexDirection: 'row'}}>@</Text>
        )
      })
    }
  </View> 
</View> 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1 
  },
  row: {
    flex: 0.8,
    flexDirection: 'row',
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! unfortunately it didn't worked, the `@` is in a row but its ignore the `flex:08` and overflow to the sides so I got one long row and not multiple rows which cover 80% of the screen horizontally as expected

Comment: The flex should be 0.8 not 08. Hope that helps otherwise I'm not sure :(